# how to get web page content consecutively without refresh url in web view android?

Tags: java, android, webview, jsoup

i working on android application with web view there is one page and Url is

same but below content change consecutively how i do check content of web

page in web view which is change and i can catch a successful message

kindly help me i searched a whole day but i did not find solution.

```
  webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webview.loadUrl(url);
        contentView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contentView);

        //Main m=new Main(this);
       // m.passData();

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Document doc = null;
                //  Element element;
                try {
                    String url = "http://example.com/";
                    doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
                    e = doc.select("div.container").first().parents();
                    a = e.toString();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        contentView.setText(a);
                    }
                });
            }
        }).start();
```

Comment: it can possible using JavaScriptInterface in android side and you also have to do some modification on Website

Comment: @NiravJoshi why would the website need modification? I agree with the js interface, e.g. register an eventhandler or check periodically for changes.